# Not output in terminal . No input asked in terminal

Tags: python, json, dictionary, input, terminal

So have just started learning python 3.
So we were provided with json file which contains contains meaning of words(It is a English dictionary).
So we had a exercise in which we have to type the word and we will get a definition for it.
But when I execute the code , the terminal is empty , I don't get any output.
Here is the code:-

```
import json
data = json.load(open("076 data.json"))

def Dictionary(Word):
    key = str(input("Enter the word here : "))
    return data[key]
    print(Dictionary(key))
```

What might be going wrong in this

Comment: Do you call *Dictionary*?

Comment: the file("076 data.json") is english dictionary @Daniil

Comment: You need to call *Dictionary* the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the provided code, you only *define* the function, you do not *execute* the function. You need to call the function (after defining it). For instance:

```py
import json
data = json.load(open("076 data.json"))

def Dictionary():
    key = input("Enter the word here : ")
    print(data[key])

Dictionary()
```